# ASP.NET : Get Label inside Repeater using JQuery based on custom attribute

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, web

i read so many solutions and blogs on this but still not able to get it done.

I have a Repeater in my code, which has labels in ItemTemplate. I need to do a client side validation (using jQuery) on the values entered in the TextBox on a button click event. i have some value in my label which I want to access to make comparision between the values entered in the textbox and text of label. Now I added a custom attribute named datakey to the label and textbox both, so that comparision is easy.

I access the text box and get the datakey attribute.
I get the label with the datakey value same as that of textbox and do my comparision.

Now in Jquery I am not able to access that label.

This is what i wrote in Jquery:

```
var lbl = $("label").find("[datakey='" + expID + "']");
```

ASP Code.

```
<table class="tblDispData">
    <asp:Repeater ID="PrjBudgetDetails" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <tr>
                <th class="thDataDisp">
                    <asp:Label ID="LbExpType" runat="server" Text="Expenditure Type" CssClass="LbTblDataDisp"
                        Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                </th>
                <th class="thDataDisp">
                    <asp:Label ID="LbAllocatedBudget" runat="server" Text="Allocated Budget" CssClass="LbTblDataDisp"
                        Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                </th>
                <th class="thDataDisp">
                    <asp:Label ID="LbAvailedBudget" runat="server" Text="Available Budget" CssClass="LbTblDataDisp"
                        Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                </th>
                <th class="thDataDisp">
                    <asp:Label ID="LbRequestedBudget" runat="server" Text="Budget Requested" CssClass="LbTblDataDisp"
                        Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td class="tdDataDisp">
                    <asp:Label ID="ExpTypeText" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ExpType") %>' CssClass="LbTblDataDisp"
                        AssociatedControlID="BudgetRequestedText"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="tdDataDisp">
                    <asp:Label ID="BudgetAllocatedText" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("BudgetAllocated") %>'
                        CssClass="LbTblDataDisp" AssociatedControlID="BudgetRequestedText"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="tdDataDisp">
                    <asp:Label ID="BudgetAvailableText" runat="server" dataKey='<%#Eval("ExpID") %>'
                        Text='<%#Convert.ToDouble(Eval("BudgetAllocated")) - Convert.ToDouble(Eval("BudgetAvailed")) %>'
                        CssClass="LbTblDataDisp" ClientIDMode="Static" AssociatedControlID="BudgetRequestedText"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="tdDataDisp">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="BudgetRequestedText" runat="server" dataKey='<%#Eval("ExpID") %>'
                        dataValue='<%#Eval("ExpType") %>' CssClass="tblDataInput"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <span id="Legend1" class="frmInstructions" runat="server">Please enter zero(0) if not
                requesting budget for any particular expenditure. The currency is INR. </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="prjBudgetSubmitBtn" runat="server" Text="Submit Budget" CssClass="formNext"
                ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="prjBudgetSubmitBtn_Click" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The RESULTING MARKUP HERE

```
<table class="tblDispData">

                                <tr>
                                    <th class="thDataDisp">
                                        <span id="LbExpType" class="LbTblDataDisp" style="font-weight:bold;">Expenditure Type</span>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="thDataDisp">
                                        <span id="LbAllocatedBudget" class="LbTblDataDisp" style="font-weight:bold;">Allocated Budget</span>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="thDataDisp">
                                        <span id="LbAvailedBudget" class="LbTblDataDisp" style="font-weight:bold;">Available Budget</span>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="thDataDisp">
                                        <span id="LbRequestedBudget" class="LbTblDataDisp" style="font-weight:bold;">Budget Requested</span>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td class="tdDataDisp">
                                        <label for="BudgetRequestedText" id="ExpTypeText" class="LbTblDataDisp">Hardware</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="tdDataDisp">
                                        <label for="BudgetRequestedText" id="BudgetAllocatedText" class="LbTblDataDisp">9.00</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="tdDataDisp">
                                        <label for="BudgetRequestedText" id="BudgetAvailableText" class="LbTblDataDisp" dataKey="EXP001">7</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="tdDataDisp">
                                        <input name="ctl00$pageMainContent$PrjBudgetDetails$ctl01$BudgetRequestedText" type="text" id="BudgetRequestedText" class="tblDataInput" dataKey="EXP001" dataValue="Hardware" dataAmount="7" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td class="tdDataDisp">
                                        <label for="BudgetRequestedText" id="ExpTypeText" class="LbTblDataDisp">Software</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="tdDataDisp">
                                        <label for="BudgetRequestedText" id="BudgetAllocatedText" class="LbTblDataDisp">9.00</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="tdDataDisp">
                                        <label for="BudgetRequestedText" id="BudgetAvailableText" class="LbTblDataDisp" dataKey="EXP002">9</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="tdDataDisp">
                                        <input name="ctl00$pageMainContent$PrjBudgetDetails$ctl02$BudgetRequestedText" type="text" id="BudgetRequestedText" class="tblDataInput" dataKey="EXP002" dataValue="Software" dataAmount="9" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td class="tdDataDisp">
                                        <label for="BudgetRequestedText" id="ExpTypeText" class="LbTblDataDisp">Software AMC</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="tdDataDisp">
                                        <label for="BudgetRequestedText" id="BudgetAllocatedText" class="LbTblDataDisp">9.00</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="tdDataDisp">
                                        <label for="BudgetRequestedText" id="BudgetAvailableText" class="LbTblDataDisp" dataKey="EXP003">9</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="tdDataDisp">
                                        <input name="ctl00$pageMainContent$PrjBudgetDetails$ctl03$BudgetRequestedText" type="text" id="BudgetRequestedText" class="tblDataInput" dataKey="EXP003" dataValue="Software AMC" dataAmount="9" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td class="tdDataDisp">
                                        <label for="BudgetRequestedText" id="ExpTypeText" class="LbTblDataDisp">Hardware AMC</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="tdDataDisp">
                                        <label for="BudgetRequestedText" id="BudgetAllocatedText" class="LbTblDataDisp">9.00</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="tdDataDisp">
                                        <label for="BudgetRequestedText" id="BudgetAvailableText" class="LbTblDataDisp" dataKey="EXP004">9</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="tdDataDisp">
                                        <input name="ctl00$pageMainContent$PrjBudgetDetails$ctl04$BudgetRequestedText" type="text" id="BudgetRequestedText" class="tblDataInput" dataKey="EXP004" dataValue="Hardware AMC" dataAmount="9" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td class="tdDataDisp">
                                        <label for="BudgetRequestedText" id="ExpTypeText" class="LbTblDataDisp">UPS</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="tdDataDisp">
                                        <label for="BudgetRequestedText" id="BudgetAllocatedText" class="LbTblDataDisp">9.00</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="tdDataDisp">
                                        <label for="BudgetRequestedText" id="BudgetAvailableText" class="LbTblDataDisp" dataKey="EXP006">9</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="tdDataDisp">
                                        <input name="ctl00$pageMainContent$PrjBudgetDetails$ctl05$BudgetRequestedText" type="text" id="BudgetRequestedText" class="tblDataInput" dataKey="EXP006" dataValue="UPS" dataAmount="9" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3">
                                <span id="pageMainContent_Legend1" class="frmInstructions">Please enter zero(0) if not
                                    requesting budget for any particular expenditure. The currency is INR. </span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" name="ctl00$pageMainContent$prjBudgetSubmitBtn" value="Submit Budget" id="prjBudgetSubmitBtn" class="formNext" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us some of the resulting markup

Comment: Well even though I figured it out, I was able to access the TextBox so I added that custom attribute to the Textbox and made my comparison. I will post my resulting markup showing label tag.

Comment: A Repeater is purely on the server side. It has two effects on the client side: (1) it changes the client ID's of the controls, depending on your ClientIdMode (2) repeats the controls inside the ItemTemplate. Often I find that it's easiest to validate controls inside a repeater by assigning a CSS class. This works particularly well when the value doesn't depend on anything else, such as when you want to make sure a date or phone number is formatted correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code will give you the related label.

```
$("label[dataKey='" + expID + "']")
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u3hLa5nk/)

Comment: `.find()` will search the matching sub elements. if you use the `.filter()` it will give the same result as in the answer